# Phaser using SASS Compass Sprites

Tags: css, sass, sprite, compass, phaser-framework

I'm building a game using the Phaser javascript framework and want to use my compass-generated sprite classes from the SASS/CSS.

Can I use my generated classes on Phaser, and if so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Update tag to better reflect that phaser is meant as the Javascript framework (and not the Java synchronization barrier)

Comment: as far as i do understand you can add any stylesheet in the index.html of your game. Phaser ships with grunt tasks, you can add your own task to compile your compass sprites. See https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass

Comment: y, i know this, but when I load sprites is just point to the image file! I want to know if I can use my SASS classes on canvas

Answer (score 1):

Since a Phaser game is one single <canvas> element, you can't use CSS to style specific game objects.

BUT, while I don't know much about SASS, maybe you can manage somehow to convert your sprite classes to base64 images ; if so it seems like you could import them with a `game.cache.addImage('key', null, imageData);`.